# Edição de String recebida WebResponse

Tags: c#, string

Recebo uma informação através do `responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd().ToString();`.

Mas antes exibi-la na tela do Usuário quero editá-la. Como proceder?

Comment: A sua duvida é apenas como editar uma String ?

Comment: Sim, recebo uma serie de dados nessa string e id, hora da solicitação, hora do envio, status e antes de exibir preciso separa e editar esses dados

Comment: Forneça mais detalhes. Você está fazendo uma Web Request pra onde? O que é retornado? O que você quer editar? Pode editar sua pergunta e complementá-la?

Comment: O Método está se comunicando com uma URL e recebe como resposta o saldo de mensagens "OK 697" eu quero exibir só "697"

Comment: Voce pode fazer um replace

`responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd().ToString().Replace("OK ","");`

Comment: Valeu David deu certo!!

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com os comentários da pergunta, creio que você quis saber como alterar o conteúdo de um string. Nesse caso, o que o @David falou é uma possibilidade:

```
reponseStreamReader.ReadToEnd().ToString().Replace("OK ", "");
```

Mas há muitas funções que modifiquem um string, que são documentados [nesse link do MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.string).

Comment: Obrigado cara!!! Esse link ajudou muito!!